Connecting node-bull to redis in codesandbox - MaxRetriesPerRequestError
I'm trying to get example code for a nodejs application using bull running in codesandbox working but struggling to get the application to connect to its redis backend, getting a message
Error: MaxRetriesPerRequestError: Reached the max retries per request limit (which is 20).
The node app is copied from a helpful tutorial on medium by Shreshth Bansal: consists of
worker
const helloQueue = require('./queue');

// Function to process the task
async function printHelloWorld(job) {
    // Simulating a task that takes 5 seconds to complete
    setTimeout(() => {
        console.log("Hello, world!");
    }, 5000);
}

// Process jobs in the queue
helloQueue.process(async (job) => {
    await printHelloWorld(job);
});

queue
const Bull = require('bull');

const helloQueue = new Bull('hello', {
    redis: {
        port: 6379,
        host: '127.0.0.1',
    },
});

module.exports = helloQueue;

api
const express = require('express');
const helloQueue = require('./queue');

const app = express();
const port = 3000;

// Endpoint to trigger the background task
app.get('/hello', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        // Add a job to the queue
        await helloQueue.add({});
        res.status(200).json({ message: 'Success' });
    } catch (err) {
        console.error('Error:', err);
        res.status(500).json({ error: 'Internal server error' });
    }
});

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server is running on port ${port}`);
});

I followed instructions on how to install redis in a docker container and verified it's running (in a separate container). In this instruction there is no password protection and ports are 0.0.0.0:6379.
Is it better to run the redis backend in the same or separate container - any advice and what's the best way for a sandbox user to add/connect to Redis?
I've tried a couple of potential fixes based on other posted questions:
tls: true
enableTLSForSentinelMode:false
added to redis options objected in bull queue, which haven't worked.
While I've used codesandbox quite a bit for node/react applications I have not had much experience/need to add services like redis or diverge from provided templates, nor am I experienced with Docker/containers and the nitty gritty of connecting between containerised services and apps.

Eventually resolved this after trawling through docs/other questions and doing some Docker tutorials.
Main cause was that redis by default and for security only listens on the localhost - not sure how it got to 0.0.0.0 above, possibly the image used had different defaults, or I changed it following an answer to a similar posted question.
Either way, once the bind address is changed from localhost to 0.0.0.0 Redis also then needs the password to be set to allow incoming connections.
Needed also to change host from '127.0.0.1' to 'redis-container-name', as per docker network.
